# How do you find out what keywords your website is ranking for?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

How do you find out what keywords your website is ranking for?

Comment: This may be better answered on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) although this probably belongs on the [webmaster stack exchange site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).